# Root Interface and Object type support Protobuf-net V2.0 r668

Tags: protobuf-net

Questions for Marc Gravell(or any one else that knows the answer)

Does the latest version of protobuf-net(v2.0 r668) support serializing and deserializing objects that implement Root interfaces without them having to be a member of some other class?

One of the properties in a class that I am trying to serialize is an object array.
If I set one of the objects in the array to Int32 I get an error saying "Dynamic type is not a contract-type: Object". Why is that? (Trying to understand the limitations)

Thank you for the excellent library you have provided! We are hoping we can leverage it to reduce the amount of data transferred over the wire in our application!

Thanks in advance!
Neelima

Answer (score 0):

The underlying protobuf specification does not include any type meta - so there is literally nowhere to store anything about what type to use without stepping outside of the core specification. Now, I'm fairly pragmatic and there are number of places where protobuf-net gets somewhat... *creative* (but remaining legal in terms of the wire format) - but dynamic root objects is currently not one of them. I have some ideas, but nothing currently implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think we should be able to restructure our POCOs to get around that limitation.